# ifelse in r with two or more conditions

Tags: r

How can I use a conditional statement in R to define value in a column based on two column conditions?

**Data**

```
Term(in month)        DayLate   NEW_STATUS
12                    0         .....
24                    24        .....
17                    30        .....
9                     15        .....
36                    21        .....
```

**Pseudocode**

```
if(term <= 12){
  if(DayLate <= 14)         then NEW_STATUS = "NORM"
  if(DayLate between 15~30) then NEW_STATUS = "SPECIAL"
}else if(term > 12){
  if(DayLate <= 29)         then NEW_STATUS = "NORM"
  if(DayLate between 30~89) then NEW_STATUS = "SPECIAL"
}
```

Comment: try `ifelse(test, true_outcome, false_outcome)` or `dplyr::case_when()` or `switch`. One of them should do what you need

Comment: how is your condition for `NEW_STATUS` generated? Does it change every time and what is the `else` part for each condition ?

Comment: If "Term" <= 12 then do this: if "DayLate" <=14 result to "NORM", if "DayLate" between 15-30 result to "SPECIAL". However, if "Term">12 then do different above:  if "DayLate" <=29 result to "NORM", if "DayLate" between 30-89 result to "SPECIAL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by nested conditional statements with `ifelse()` in **base** or `if_else()`, `case_when()` in **dplyr**.

```
# data
df <- structure(list(Term = c(12L, 24L, 17L, 9L, 36L), DayLate = c(0L, 
24L, 30L, 15L, 21L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

---

**(1) base way**

```
within(df,
  NEW_STATUS <- ifelse(Term <= 12,
                       ifelse(DayLate <= 14, "NORM", "SPECIAL"),
                       ifelse(DayLate <= 29, "NORM", "SPECIAL"))
)
```

**(2) dplyr**

```
df %>% mutate(
  NEW_STATUS = case_when(
    Term <= 12 ~ if_else(DayLate <= 14, "NORM", "SPECIAL"),
    TRUE ~ ifelse(DayLate <= 29, "NORM", "SPECIAL")
  )
)
```

---

**Output**

```
#   Term DayLate NEW_STATUS
# 1   12       0       NORM
# 2   24      24       NORM
# 3   17      30    SPECIAL
# 4    9      15    SPECIAL
# 5   36      21       NORM
```